# Intranet silverlight app needs authentication and encyrption

Tags: silverlight, wcf, security, authentication

I am currently maintaining a silverlight 3 application which uses a basicHTTPBinding to talk to a web service hosted by the ASP.net web app that hosts the silverlight app.

To authenticate from the silverlight 3 app, a digest of the password is created and sent to the webservice. This allows access to the silverlight UI. That is pretty much where authentication is used.

After that, the web service is called for the various functions of the UI. The web service does not check for any authentication here on.

At the moment this app will be used on a secure intranet so I suppose the current way of working is fine.?

However, what would I need to do to make the app available on the internet?

JD